# How enable menu icons in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: icons, menu

In Ubuntu 16.04 I need to know how enable icon in menu.
For example the menu in Inkscape.

Currently Inkscape menu is shown in this mode:
[inkscape without icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt7FO.png)

I want to see icons in this mode:
[inkscape with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwlkQ.png)

I have tried to adjust the settings on the list below, but it doesn't work.

```
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true
- gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
```

Thanks.